# django-rest-framework clarification on field "required" option

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have the following serializer:

```
class ReqSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
           model = Earth
           fields = ('area', )
```

and this model:

```
class Earth(models.Model):
      area = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

According to django-rest-framework [Serializer fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/) the "**required**" option is 
set to True by default which means if I try to validate the serializer without "area" field in the input,
I should get `This field is required` error. But `is_valid()` is passed and the model gets created with default `area=0`. However, Using this:

```
 extra_kwargs = {
     area': {'required': True},
 }
```

Would solve the issue but why? What could change this behavior? Why the default "required=True"
has no effect?

**Update:**
I just noticed that if I remove the `default=0` from the model, it will work as expected. Now the question is why setting default on model field cancels the `required=True` on serializer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem here is that the field is being automatically generated by Django REST framework, while the docs are coming from the perspective of you manually creating the field on the serializer.

> According to django-rest-framework Serializer fields the "required" option is set to True by default

This is correct for fields that you specify on your own on the serializer. In the case of automatically generated fields, Django REST framework tries to determine the serializer field options that best match the model field, similar to how the [Django forms does it for form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types). For serializer fields, this is largely undocumented at the moment so there is nothing that I can point you to.

> But is_valid() is passed and the model gets created with default area=0.

This is because Django REST framework determines that the field has a default value, at which point is knows input is *not strictly required* because **the model field will automatically give a default value** in the event that the user passes nothing in. Of course, if you pass something into the serializer on creation, the value will be used instead of the default, which is what you would expect if you were manually creating the model.

> Would solve the issue but why? What could change this behavior? Why the default "required=True" has no effect?

This will fix your issue because it is manually overriding the `required=False` that is set on the automatically generated serializer field. In Django REST framework 3.0, you can confirm that by [calling `repr(ReqSerializer())` and looking at the the automatically generated field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#inspecting-a-modelserializer).

> I just noticed that if I remove the default=0 from the model, it will work as expected.

This is because Django REST framework no longer determines the default and adds the `required=True` to the serializer, like you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. DRF begs a decent documentation.